# Collection efficiency

Tags: java, android, performance, collections

I am concerning that I am developing an application where I need to just validate the data from the hashtables. I have 8 hash tables and I get the data from them and verify it. All 8 hashtables has the same structure. My question is if I put data in 8 hashtables would it be more efficient or if I change it in one hashtable? Each hashtable has around 100 objects.

Thanks in advance.

Yours,
Geek

Comment: Efficiency -- how so? There's not even enough context to compare likelihood of collision.

Comment: Performance revolving around a hundred elements in any data structure is not worth concerning yourself with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that in this case the size is so small as to be insignificant.

That said, use a single hash table; otherwise you'd have to do 8 checks to find something, and have the overhead of 8 hash table structures (which by definition have an overhead for the slots used to perform well).

If you are using primitive types (or even just primitive types for keys in a map), I highly recommend the trove high performance collection library ([GNU Trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/)). They are written for high performance computing, and in an environment like android can save you precious memory and compute cycles.

They are not complete drop-in replacements, but have comparable functionality...e.g.

```
TLongObjectHashMap<String> myMap; // a map from primitive long to strings 
myMap = new TLongObjectHashMap<String>();
myMap.put(4L, "Hello world"); // no boxing, so much less memory overhead, etc.
```

Comment: I was thinking in the same way but I want to confirm.